# SQLAlchemy query result is None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this issue that I don't understand.

I have `SELECT()` query that returns thousands of rows. For memory issues, I let it return one result row at a time. Then I transform the results to a dict.

```
select_query = select([table1,table2]).where(all_filters)
res = conn.execute(select_query)
row = res.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    row = res.fetchone()
    print row is None
```

The results are :

```
False
False
False
False
True
```

Why does it still show true even if it should stop when `row is None`??

So later when I want to create a dict using : `row = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))`
I get the error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

I'm new to Python, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Python-specific, instead it is a property of the `while` loop in any language. I assume that you are processing the rows inside the loop, so consider this:

```
row = res.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    row = res.fetchone()
    print row is None
    processRow(row)
```

During last iteration, `res.fetchone()` returns `None`, which is then assigned to `row`, which becomes `None`. Then, the `processRow` statement is executed before the `while` condition is checked, so it evaluates `processRow(None)`. Only *after*, during the following iteration, the `row is not None` condition is false and the loop terminates. There is nothing wrong with this code, it's exactly how it's meant to work.

A possible solution is checking for `None` *before* processing, inside the loop:

```
while True:
    row = res.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        break
    processRow(row)
```

Or, if the query set is small, you could even fetch them all and process with:

```
for row in res.fetchall():
    processRow(row)
```

Comment: I have removed `row = res.fetchone()` before the loop and added your first solution, but printing row outside the loop at the end returns `None`...

Comment: Yes. With the code above, you need to process things inside the loop (where I put a `processRow` delegate). Anyway, if you do it after the loop, then you would processing only the last row (and loosing all the others).